# Login Application

Tags: sql, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am working on the login application and currently working on the Angular JS part. As I am new to Angular JS I am stuck at it. I have writted the connection code to connect my sql database with the project

```
public bool ValidateLogin(string email, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionFactory conFac = new ConnectionFactory();
                string query = "pro_loginuser";
                SqlParameter[] parameter = new SqlParameter[2];
                parameter[0] = new SqlParameter("email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                parameter[0].Value = email;
                parameter[1] = new SqlParameter("password", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                parameter[1].Value = password;
                DataTable dt = conFac.executeSelectStoredProc(query, parameter);
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    var isSuccess = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                       select c.Field<bool>("isSuccess")).FirstOrDefault();
                    return isSuccess;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }

        public CallerEntry GetUserDetails(string email,string password)
        {
            CallerEntry callerentry = new CallerEntry();
            try
            {
                ConnectionFactory conFac = new ConnectionFactory();
                string query = "pro_loginuserdetails";
                SqlParameter[] parameter = new SqlParameter[2];
                parameter[0] = new SqlParameter("email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                parameter[0].Value = email;
                parameter[1] = new SqlParameter("password", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                parameter[1].Value = password;
                DataTable dt = conFac.executeSelectStoredProc(query, parameter);
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    callerentry = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                               select new CallerEntry
                               {
                                   vid = c.Field<int>("id"),
                                   fname=c.Field<string>("fname"),
                                   lname = c.Field<string>("lname"),
                                   branch = c.Field<int>("branch"),
                                   role = c.Field<int>("role")

                               }).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                return callerentry;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

    }
```

Getusere code is to get the other details of the user after login. The web api code is also done

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Project/ValidateLogin/{email}/{password}")]
    //e.g http://localhost:52352/api/Project/ValidateLogin/ABC@GMAIL.COM/TEST123
    public bool ValidateLogin(string email, string password)
    {
        return bal.ValidateLogin(email, password);
    }
```

Now I am unable to work on the next step where I get the credentials from web api and move ahead with login success or failure. I should enter the next page after login

Angular code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('login', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:52352/api/Project/ValidateLogin/' + emailId)
        $http.get('http://localhost:52352/api/Project/ValidateLogin/' + password)
        function()
        {

        }
        }

            });
        };

    }
  ]);
```

Comment: In general I would be using the below to hit a login API and use the response to proceed if you are managing the routing in Angular.

var data = new FormData();
data.append('user', userID);
data.append('pass', password);
$http.post('login', data, {
 withCredentials : false,
 transformRequest : angular.identity,
 headers : {
  'Content-Type' : undefined
       }
 }).success(function(response) {
             /// HERE USE YOUR RESPONSE TO MANIPULATE
         })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new Js file name as loginService.js and include loginService.js file in your index.html or main page

```
(function () {
   var loginService = function ($http) {

    var baseURL = "http://localhost:52352";//Set one global variable to get base URL, So it will be easy to handle in future

    var validateUser = function (email, password) {
        var uri = baseURL + 'api/Project/ValidateLogin/' + email + "/" + password;
        return $http.get(uri)
        .then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
        });
    };

    return {
        validateUser: validateUser
    };
};

  angular.module('myApp').factory("loginService", ["$http", loginService]);
}());
```

Create new Js file name as LoginController.js and include LoginController.js file in your index.html or main page

```
(function () {
   var LoginController = function ($scope, loginService) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        //$scope.email and $scope.password these value you can get from ng-model from your Html control of views i.e. as follows
        //<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" placeholder="email" />
        //<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" />\

        loginService.validateUser($scope.email,$scope.password).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $location.path('/home');//Redirect to homepage
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }, errorDetails);
    }

};
angular.module('myApp').controller("LoginController", ['$scope', 'loginService', LoginController]);

}());
```

Comment: why there are 2 js files required? Can't we merge them both into loginController.js file?

Comment: Yes you can write service code in Controller, But when you use code separately like above then it will be helpful you to manage easily when your application grows.

Read this:- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: J-Mean:  yes you are right but I am suppose to add into a single controller as this is the whole application's login part only. I have merged the code like this. Is it correct?

Comment: angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,$http) {
      $scope.Login = function (emailId,password){
          var uri = 'http://localhost:64367' + 'api/Project/ValidateLogin/' + emailId + "/" + password;
          $http.get(uri).then(function (data) {
              if (data) {
                  $location.path('/home');//Redirect to homepage
              } else {
                  return;
              }   }
          }])

Comment: Please use as follows:-

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.Login = function (emailId, password) {
        var uri = 'http://localhost:64367/api/Project/ValidateLogin/' + emailId + "/" + password;

        $http.get(uri).then(function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $location.path('/home');//Redirect to homepage 
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}])

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I am using this code but whenever I am entering username and password its just refreshing page. No correct result